# Twilio Studio Flow - Handle Custom Channel

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-autopilot

Is it possible to integrate custom channels with Studio Flows?

From the documentation, it is possible to trigger a flow using a REST API for the flow.

But it is not clear how to send / get replies from the custom channel after the flow has started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Once you trigger a Studio Flow, everything else gets run through the Studio Flow. So you can't, for example, start a Studio Flow with a REST API Trigger by an incoming Twitter DM and then continue the conversation through Studio.